# Getting Script error while logged in into Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, login

I am getting the following error while logged into the Stack Overflow.
My firefox version is 32.0.3
[image]

Comment: Nothing to do with your version of FF. Looks like you or your ISP is blocking JavaScript from the CDN. Check why cdn.sstatic.com is blocked.

Comment: You might check [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/158100) that explains what is supported and needed.